# Method to construct non-UFD rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra

You know all the usual examples...
$$
\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] \; : \; 6 = 2\cdot3 =(1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})\\\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}] \; : \; 8 = 2\cdot2\cdot2 = (1+\sqrt{-7})(1-\sqrt{-7}) \\
\cdots$$
What kind of generalization exists to find these simple non-UFD rings?

Comment: $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$ where $d \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, or more generally *any integral domain that is not integrally closed*. All UFDs are integrally closed.

Comment: Rings of integers of an algebraic number field of class number $h>1$. Note: While $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is the ring of integers of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$, your other ring is not the full ring of integers of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$ (for it is not integrally closed in its field of fractions). In fact, the slightly bigger ring $\Bbb{Z}[(-1+\sqrt{-7})/2]$ turns out to be a UFD.